# Scroll view scrolling always back to the top

Tags: xcode

I have a scroll view full of objects loaded from a json file. Every 3 seconds the data is reloaded, and nothing really changes (unless a user added new data). The reloading is very fast, but the scroll view scrolls back to the top. I want it to remain in the point where it was. How can I do this?

I use this code to delete everything for reloading:

```
[scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

And then I repopulate the scroll view. When reloading, the frame of the scroll view vil return to the initial value, and only the addition of the objects will make it expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is under the assumption that you are setting the UIScrollView's contentSize with each object received from the JSON file:

When that first object gets loaded from the JSON file again, it sets the contentSize really low, therefore scrolling to the top.

You really don't want to remove everything from the UIScrollView before adding all of the objects back though. You should instead cache the objects that are in there and only do it if there is a change. Even when there is a change I would look into maybe just appending the changes rather than removing and re-adding objects.

Comment: How do I chache the objects, so check if there is a change in the Json file or not?

Comment: There's really no "catch-all" answer here, but what I would do is make custom Objective-C objects out of each JSON object and override the isEqual method and check everything that you need to in there. I know that is vague, but like I said there really isn't a "catch-all" answer.